# Reference a cell that is defined in a string in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet set up as follows:

```
$B$13 = the string "'TopCap'!$C$12"
$D$13 = the string "'TopCap'!$E$12"
```

The cell in Worksheet TopCap cell $C$12 has the formula that the Goal Seek needs. And TopCap!$E$12 is where the changing cell is.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Range("$B$13").GoalSeek _
        goal:=Range("$C$13").Value, _
        ChangingCell:=Range("$D$13").Value

End Sub
```

How do I write the code to have the GoalSeek Range look in the cell in TopCap for the formula?
Like Range('TopCap'!$C$12).GoalSeek _

I hope I have described this well.
Please ask if I need to describe it better.

Any assistance is appreciated.
Rich

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest a couple of [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx)s; one to put the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) and another one wrapping the first to use the cell's value to define the range.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Range(Range("B13").Value).GoalSeek _
        Goal:=Range(Range("C13").Value), _
        ChangingCell:=Range(Range("D13").Value)

End Sub
```

So `Range(Range("D13").Value).Address(external:=True)` will resolve to TopCap'!$E$12.

I've removed the **$** absolute anchors from the string cell addresses. As strings, they are not going to change and are unnecessary. This is a Private Sub so parent worksheet references may not be necessary (e.g. `Range("D13").Value`) but wrapping that in a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: I now have it like this.
    Range(Range("B13").Value).GoalSeek _
    Goal:=Range("C13").Value, _
    ChangingCell:=Range(Range("D13").Value)
it gives me the error: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.
the Goal range is on the home page, so I don't think we need to nest it.

Comment: Yes, you provided only two cells with cell addresses in them but I used three. My bad; I was trying to be thorough and misinterpreted what I thought was a shortcoming in the example.

Comment: No Problem.
But any idea on what the error is all about?
Even a simple line fails with the same error.

 MsgBox ("The value is: " & Range(Range("B13").Value)) fails.

Comment: Not off the top of my head but then again, I know very little about your project. I was concerned about parent worksheet references; that is likely the issue but I don't even know what workshett that private sub belongs in.

Comment: Everything is on one sheet (Sheet1) except the GoalSeek formula and the ChangingCell.  The command button, this GoalSeek command routine all on this sheet.